# Windows Explorer Slow Viewing SAMBA Shares

Tags: samba

Windows explorer sometimes "hangs" for up to 150s when viewing some samba file shares.
ProcMon shows the NotifyChangeDirectory is taking a long time.

Is there any way to alleviate this issue?

Client Windows 10
Server Ubuntu 20.04

[image]

Comment: Make sure smb.conf is properly set up in Ubuntu so that there is no credential delay. None here connecting Windows to Ubuntu Desktop. Make sure otherwise Explorer is not hanging up (Windows issue).

Comment: Using a shortcut to the full UNC path, I find, is *much* more reliable when connecting Windows *via* smb. See if that also speeds connecting, if you're not already using UNC path.

Comment: This sure is a windows (explorer) issue John.